# Can a Mac enter sleep mode on schedule when a third party app tries to prevent sleep?

Tags: macos, mac, sleep-wake

There’s a third party software I have running on my Mac in the menu bar at all times, but for some reason it’s preventing my Mac mini from sleeping or locking the screen altogether. I contacted the company about this issue, but just in case I won’t be able to resolve it with them, is there a way I can prevent a Mac app from preventing it from sleeping, without quitting the app altogether?

Comment: What's the app?

Comment: It's called Reference 4 Systemwide, its an audio app I'm using on my Mac.

Answer (score 3):

No. Power manager assertions can be artificially created (e.g., via `caffeinate`) but they can’t be removed except by the app itself. You can, at least, view the current assertions via

```
pmset -g assertions
```

and see what kind of assertion your app has taken.